# Fermenting temperature in Queensland Australia

Tags: fermentation-temperature

Being my very first brew...and from a kit. I worked on just room temperature.....Im in Queensland Australia. So between 24 and 28 degrees Celsius. Which I found out is too high? Kit never stated anything about specific temp. Probably shouldve done some research! How would this affect my beer? Should I then let my beer mature in the bottles at the same temperature range or in the fridge?

Comment: Im just updating! All comments that I found on the Brigalow homebrew kit stated that it is just a average or under par beer.....not so! Between you guys on here....my brew shop and my very knowledgeable brewer mate and neighbour.....Ive listened and tweaked some with the brewing times.....fermentation temps and times! Tried one yesterday.....bottled 31/12/16....fermented at room temperature  (queensland had some serious heatwaves the past month)till 13th of Jan and chilled in the fridge since ! Beautiful....beautiful!!! So mu advice.....dont give up (cause everyone says its crap) till tasted!!

Comment: Ive still got 9 at room temperature and 20 fermenting in the fridge. Im documenting everything I do with the brew down to days and hours. And Ill keep tasting at different intervals. But what I tasted yesterday was unbelievably crisp and smooth! Im so glad I started on this journey! Thanx for the advice! When Ive documented the whole process....Ill post it up! Love to hear comments from the backyard"Pro Brewers".

Answer (score 1):

High temperature may give you fruity esters, phenols and other substances like that. Probably still better than "eurolager" or other mass-produced beer, but not great for most styles.  As long as you stay under 30°C, yeast should do pretty fine and batch should work out to be drinkable.

With your temperatures, I sure hope you like belgian styles, because yeast for them kinda like it hot:

- [Wyeast 1388](https://www.wyeastlab.com/yeast-strain/belgian-strong-ale) up to 80F / 28°C
- [Wyeast 1214](https://www.wyeastlab.com/yeast-strain/belgian-abbey-style-ale) up to 78F / 26°C
- [White Labs WLP550](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast-bank/wlp550-belgian-ale-yeast) up to 78F/ 26°C
- [Fermentum Mobile FM26](http://www.fermentum-mobile.pl/en/portfolio-item/fm26/) up to 24°C  officially, I had good effect even near 28°C
- Mangrove Jack's - Belgian Ale M27 likes it up to 32°C. Might be discontinued as I can't find it on their page now, but still avaliable in the stores.
- and  more

As you can see, your temperatures are pretty OK with any style that calls for belgian yeast.

---

I have no affiliation with any of manufacturers listed. I'm only an user.

Comment: Thank you! I did learn that I could brew my beer in a fridge....thats where Ill go next!

Comment: Like I said....some research wouldnt have gone astray! I didnt even think about different strains of yeast or different recipes or anything really.....just saw the kit and thought Ill give it a go!

Comment: @JacoGroenewald with fridge, this is another matter. You definitely do not want to go too cold! For ales, can your fridge hold stable 15 to 20°C? Most off the shelf fridges have, like, 10°C max so it would limit you to the lagers.

Comment: My local homebrew shop....which I found after the fact actually sells a little box you plug into the wall and fridge into the box....then you can set it at any degree you want! He brews hes beer at 18°Celsius. Most of his beer anyway.

Comment: @JacoGroenewald Lucky you. Nothing like that in shops in my area. Glad you have this figured out. Don't be shy to answer your own question and write about this fridge. With pictures, pleas :D

Comment: @JacoGroenewald I just ordered yeast that likes it at 24 to 32°C - I'll update my answer because it looks just perfect for you :)

Comment: Awesome! I will definitely post pics of the fridges when I get around there again. Well my brew is about ready to bottle. Looks like beer.....smells like beer (maybe a little yeasty)....tastes almost like beer! Think I might bottle half and leave the rest another week and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Hothead Yeast](http://www.omegayeast.com/portfolio/14158-2/) from Omega it has a broad temperature range 62-98° F (16-37° C) and is reported to give a [slightly fruity flavour profile](http://scottjanish.com/omega-hothead-ale-oyl-057-yeast/).